# Android Room one to many relationship

Tags: android, android-room

I'm attempting to create a one-to-many relationship where each instance of `user` corresponds to zero or more instances of `role` entity.

**Problem:** `UserRoleJunction` is having issues in the `@Relation` for both `parentColumn` (user) and `entityColumn` (role)

I didn't reach to `DAO` implementation yet because of the error.

**user**

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username |   name   |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | johndoe  | John Doe |
|  2 | janedoe  | Jane Doe |
+----+----------+----------+
```

**data class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) 
    var id: Long,
    var username: String? = null,
    var name: String? = null)
```

---

**role**

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Sales    |
|  2 | Shipping |
|  3 | Accounts |
+----+----------+
```

**data class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "role")
data class Role(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long,
    var name: String? = null)
```

---

**user_role** Join or CrossRef Table

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | role_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
|       1 |       3 |
|       2 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

**data class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_role", primaryKeys = ["user_id", "role_id"])
data class UserRoleJoin( // CrossRef
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id") var userId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "role_id") var roleId: Int)
```

---

**Junction data class**

```
data class UserRoleJunction (
    @Embedded var user: User,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id", // User -> error: see below
        entityColumn = "id", // Role -> error: see below
        associateBy = Junction(UserRoleJoin::class)
    )
    var roles: List<Role>
)
```

---

**Error 1** UserRoleJunction

**parentColumn**

> error: Cannot find the parent entity referencing column `id` in the junction `UserRoleJoin`. Options: `user_id`, `role_id`

**entityColumn**

> error: Cannot find the child entity referencing column `id` in the junction `UserRoleJoin`. Options: `user_id`, `role_id`

I did try substituting `user_id` and `role_id` as per the error messages but it keeps throwing similar errors like above.

**Error 2** UserRoleJunction

> Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a association/junction there are 4 columns involved.

Two parents and two children. The parentColumn and entityColumn at the `@Relation` level define the columns in the `@Relation` (Role) and the `@Embedded` (User) tables.

The `Junction` is used to specify the respective columns in the junction table itself, these have been omitted and are the cause of the errors.

So you should be using:-

```
Junction(UserRoleJoin::class, parentColumn = "user_id", entityColumn = "role_id")
```

Comment: Thanks. Why these attributes are omitted from the official reference? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships

Comment: @Source because the columns in the junction table (mapping, reference, associative table .....) are the same as the columns in the referenced/associated/mapped table in the example. Of course you can have the junction table having two columns named id so this short version cannot be used in your case. If you follow the links to Junction, then the attributes are described. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Junction